# How to automate the Microsoft Graph API Authorization request process

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, authorization, office365

I've successfully developed a web application that allows end users to make time reservations. To enhance user experience and productivity, I aim to automate the synchronization of these reservations with Microsoft Outlook using the Microsoft Graph API and Microsoft Azure. Could you guide the steps and best practices to seamlessly integrate the reservation data into users' Outlook calendars, ensuring a smooth and efficient process for reservation management and Outlook synchronization?

Need Support for automation of this process
[image: outlook Process]

[image: wwddfvr]

[image: otlook2]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to "Azure Active Directory" > "App registrations" and create a new application registration.
Note down the Application (client) ID and Directory (tenant) ID.
In the Azure portal, go to your app registration, then navigate to "API permissions."
Add the required permissions for Microsoft Graph (e.g., Calendars.ReadWrite for calendar access).
In the app registration, go to "Certificates & Secrets" to create a new client secret.
Use OAuth 2.0 for user authentication. You'll need to redirect users to Microsoft for authentication and obtain an access token